# Will I be able to play my Destiny Characters if I buy Legendary Edition (PS3)

Tags: destiny

So I have Destiny on PS3. If I were to buy the Legendary Edition (Containing House of Wolves and Dark Below Expansion) will I be able to play with my characters from my original Destiny disc? May sound silly, but I need confirmation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. You're not actually buying a new game, you're buying the same game with added content.